# How can I add a geometry column in using pgAdmin?

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, pgadmin, geom

The following is the scripts I was using:

```
ALTER TABLE locations ADD COLUMN geom geometry(PointZ,4326);
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE steven_requests ADD COLUMN geom geometry(PointZ,...
                                                    ^
SQL state: 42704



Character: 45
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geometry 
seems ok. have you installed postgis?

Comment: "*but didn't work*" is not a valid Postgres error message. Please **[edit]** your question and add the full error message you got.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies for not providing the right information. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to deal with this extension:

I went into the application folder on my mac, then I opened the Postgresql folder, and then opened "Application stack builder"; from there, I was able to install the PostGIS extension.

Finally, this query was able to work:

```
ALTER TABLE locations ADD COLUMN geom geometry(PointZ,4326);
```